# How can I parallelise the upload of a directory by FTP?

Tags: command-line, ftp, parallelism, file-transfer

I need to upload a directory with a rather complicated tree (lots of subdirectories, etc.) by FTP. I am unable to compress this directory, since I do not have any access to the destination apart from FTP - e.g. no tar. Since this is over a very long distance (USA => Australia), latency is quite high.

Following the advice in [How to FTP multiple folders to another server using mput in Unix?](https://serverfault.com/q/91149/174582), I am currently using `ncftp` to perform the transfer with `mput -r`. Unfortunately, this seems to transfer a single file at a time, wasting a lot of the available bandwidth on communication overhead.

Is there any way I can parallelise this process, i.e. upload multiple files from this directory at the same time? Of course, I could manually split it and execute `mput -r` on each chunk, but that's a tedious process.

A CLI method is heavily preferred, as the client machine is actually a headless server accessed via SSH.

Comment: Would `rsync` be an option? **edit** apparently not, as it doesn't work over ftp. Might be worth asking the destination server admin whether he's willing to give you `sftp` access - you wouldn't be able to log in, but `rsync` would work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

lftp would do this with the command `mirror -R -P 20 localpath` - mirror syncs between locations, and -R uses the remote server as the destination , with P doing 20 parallel transfers at once.

As explained in `man lftp`:

```
   mirror [OPTS] [source [target]]

   Mirror specified source directory to local target directory. If  target
   directory ends with a slash, the source base name is appended to target
   directory name. Source and/or target can be URLs pointing  to  directo‐
   ries.


        -R,    --reverse                 reverse mirror (put files)
        -P,    --parallel[=N]            download N files in parallel
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try using [gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) and curl to automate it.

then you could do something such as:

```
find . -t f -name "*.pdf" | parallel -j 4 curl -T {} ftp://ftp.site.com --user me:pass
```

This will run 4 jobs per cpu uploading all pdfs in working path.

Comment: The is one possible approach, but has the drawback of needing to authenticate once for every file - again, a lot of overhead made worse by high latency.